# for loop executing only for first iteration

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following `for` loop which is appending a `rect` to a `group` element:

```
var svg_container = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
                                        .attr('width', width)
                                        .attr('height', 50)

var legend_group = svg_container.append('g');

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    legend_group.append('rect')
                                .attr('x', i += 10)
                                .attr('y', 5)
                                .attr('width', 10)
                                .attr('height', 5)
                                .attr('fill', 'red')
}
```

But it is running only for `i = 0` and there are no errors. However, when I remove the `attr` chaining, it works as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    legend_group.append('rect');
}
```

Why is the `for` loop not executing for each iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because in this line you are chainging `i` itself to more than `5`.

```
.attr('x', i += 10)
```

You should have it, readonly like `.attr('x', i + 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding +10 to i in this line .attr('x', i += 10).I guess you need something like i+10

Answer (score 1):

The for loop's second field is a condition that is checked before every loop run. Inside your loop you're adding 10 to i and assigning it at the same time. after the first run the loop logic sees that i is 10 and exits because the condition (i < 5) is not met anymore. Simply change `i += 10` to `i + 10` or `i * 10`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you add 10 to your increment counter in the first loop:

```
.attr('x', i += 10)
```

After that, in the first iteration, `i` is 10, which is greater that your limit.

Most likely you are using the same variable by mistake, but there is not enough information here. But if you do, change the `i` inside your loop, or the `i` in the `for` loop conditions